# mesureText() returning big number

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In my app the user can dynamically add either text or an image from an input bar.  The text is inside a span element.  After all the images and text is added, the user can click a button to add it to the canvas.  When adding text to the canvas I use measureText() to get the texts width so that I can place it nicely beside the image.

But when I use it, it returns a huge number that's always the same no matter how big the text is (303 px).  What could be causing this?

```
if (divEl){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
            for(var n=0; n<imgDiv.children.length; n++){
                if (imgDiv.children[n].nodeName === "IMG"){
                    ctx.drawImage(imgDiv.children[n], prevX ,0)
                    prevX += imgDiv.children[n].width
                    console.log(imgDiv.children[n].width)
                }
                else if(imgDiv.children[n].nodeName === "SPAN"){
                    ctx.font = window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize + " Open Sans"
                    ctx.fillText(imgDiv.children[n].innerHTML,prevX ,parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize,10))
                    prevX += ctx.measureText(imgDiv.children[n]).width
                }
            }
            var imagedata = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
            canvas.width = prevX
            ctx.putImageData(imagedata,0,0)
        }
        console.log(canvas.width)
        console.log(canvas.height)
        console.log(imagedata)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you alter the width of the canvas element using CSS? `#canvas { width: 999px !important }`

Comment: Here is what happens.  It makes it bigger, but when inspecting it it has the same width (303 px) https://imgur.com/a/afDT4